# ASP .NET MVC Deployment issue on the host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I am trying to deploy a MVC application on IIS7. The IIS is configured to integrated pipeline. When I am using the full path (for example: http://mysite/Controller/Action), I am getting - 404 Not Found.

The MVC is installed on the hosting server.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Do you have the site set up as an application associated with an app pool?

Comment: Yes. The application has app pool.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a configuration issue, but you might want to check out the [ASP.NET Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to see what the server thinks is going on.

Comment: I have tried to use ASP .NET Routing Debugger but I am getting the same error (Not Found).

Comment: Ok, then something really isn't wired up correctly. It sounds like you perhaps put the files in the wrong place or the site isn't configured correctly somehow.